# Running into issues with my QuadTree Implementation

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm working on implementing a Quad Tree in C++ and for the past amount of time, I haven't been able to solve my segmentation fault error. The thing is, I have pointers all over the place and not quite sure where my problem is. I already have implemented my code in different languages and simply wanted to test my C++ skills but this is getting in the way.

Here's the code:

**quadtree.h:**

```
#ifndef QUADTREE_QUADTREE_H
#define QUADTREE_QUADTREE_H

#endif //QUADTREE_QUADTREE_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x, double y);
    double x;
    double y;
};

class Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height);
    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;
    bool contains(Point* p);
};

class QuadTree
{
public:
    QuadTree();
    QuadTree(Rectangle* boundary, int capacity);
    Rectangle* boundary = new Rectangle(200,200,200,200);
    QuadTree* qt = new QuadTree(boundary, 4);
//    Rectangle* boundary;
    Point* p;
    int capacity;
    vector<Point*> points;
    QuadTree* NE;
    QuadTree* NW;
    QuadTree* SW;
    QuadTree* SE;
    bool divided;
    void subdivide();
    void buildTree();
    void insertToNode(Point* p);

};
```

**quadtree.cpp**

```
#include "quadtree.h"
#include <random>


Point::Point(double x, double y)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(double x, double y, double width, double height)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}

bool Rectangle::contains(Point* p)
{
    return (p->x > this->x - this->width && p->x < this->x + this->width && p->y > this->y - this->height && p->y < this->y + this->height);
}

QuadTree::QuadTree() {}

QuadTree::QuadTree(Rectangle* boundary, int capacity)
{
    this->boundary = boundary;
    this->capacity = capacity;
    this->divided = false;
}

void QuadTree::subdivide()
{
    Rectangle* nw = new Rectangle(this->boundary->x + this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->y - this->boundary->height/2, this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->height/2);
    Rectangle* ne = new Rectangle(this->boundary->x - this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->y - this->boundary->height/2, this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->height/2);
    Rectangle* sw = new Rectangle(this->boundary->x + this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->y + this->boundary->height/2, this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->height/2);
    Rectangle* se = new Rectangle(this->boundary->x - this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->y + this->boundary->height/2, this->boundary->width/2, this->boundary->height/2);
    this->NE = new QuadTree(ne, 1);
    this->NW = new QuadTree(nw, 1);
    this->SW = new QuadTree(sw, 1);
    this->SE = new QuadTree(se, 1);
    this->divided = true;
}

void QuadTree::buildTree()
{
    std::random_device rd; // obtain a random number from hardware
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); // seed the generator
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 199); // define the range

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        Point* p = new Point(distr(eng), distr(eng));
        this->qt->insertToNode(p);
    }
}

void QuadTree::insertToNode(Point* p)
{
    if(!this->boundary->contains(p))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(this->points.size() < this->capacity)
    {
        this->points.push_back(p);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!this->divided)
        {
            this->subdivide();
        }

    }
    this->NE->insertToNode(p);
    this->NW->insertToNode(p);
    this->SW->insertToNode(p);
    this->SE->insertToNode(p);
}
```

Comment: Run the code with a debugger attached. Check where it segfaults, work backwards from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructors will call themselves recursively until you run out of stack space.

You've specified a default value for `qt`, which will allocate another `QuadTree` item.  Since the 2 parameter constructor does not provide a different initial value for `qt`, another `QuadTree` object will be allocated, and the constructor will be called recursively until you run out of stack space or memory.

You need to rethink what `qt` is doing.  Is it even necessary?